How to build android apk file for a NRF51822?
I have to build an APK file for android from this repo. I don't know which IDE and OS to use. I found some outdated tutorial like this one. I only know that I need Linux for this but further steps are unclear.

I don't see anything that is related to Android in this project. It is simply a firmware for an embedded system.

This is how I understand the question (with a lot of guessing): You want to use the project from the linked repo on a NRF51822 and need an Android App to communicate with it. A bit of search through the other projects by that user lead me to the the VESC-Tool. There is an android app available
